# search engine using R

Tags: r, search-engine, text-analysis

I have prepared following code for search engine which provides scores of statements which needs to search in available list of documents.

```
doc1 <- "Stray cats are running all over the place. I see 10 a day!"
doc2 <- "Cats are killers. They kill billions of animals a year."
doc3 <- "The best food in Columbus, OH is   the North Market."
doc4 <- "Brand A is the best tasting cat food around. Your cat will love it."
doc5 <- "Buy Brand C cat food for your cat. Brand C makes healthy and happy cats."
doc6 <- "The Arnold Classic came to town this weekend. It reminds us to be healthy."
doc7 <- "I have nothing to say. In summary, I have told you nothing."


doc.list <- list(doc1, doc2, doc3, doc4, doc5, doc6, doc7)
N.docs <- length(doc.list)
names(doc.list) <- paste0("doc", c(1:N.docs))

query <- "Healthy cat food abcdefxyz"


### Initialize WOrk environment
libs <- c ("tm","slam", "SnowballC")
lapply(libs, require, character.only = TRUE)

my.docs <- VectorSource(c(doc.list, query))
my.docs$Names <- c(names(doc.list), "query")

my.corpus <- Corpus(my.docs)

#--------------------------------# Feature Engineering Starts#-----------------------------------------------------
toSpace <- content_transformer(function(x, pattern) gsub(pattern, " ", x))
removeSpecialChars <- function(x) gsub("[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]","",x)
my.corpus <- tm_map(my.corpus, toSpace, "/")
my.corpus <- tm_map(my.corpus, toSpace, "-")
my.corpus <- tm_map(my.corpus, toSpace, ":")
my.corpus <- tm_map(my.corpus, toSpace, ";")
my.corpus <- tm_map(my.corpus, toSpace, "@")
my.corpus <- tm_map(my.corpus, toSpace, "\\(" )
my.corpus <- tm_map(my.corpus, toSpace, ")")
my.corpus <- tm_map(my.corpus, toSpace, ",")
my.corpus <- tm_map(my.corpus, toSpace, "_")
my.corpus <- tm_map(my.corpus, content_transformer(removeSpecialChars))
my.corpus <- tm_map(my.corpus, content_transformer(tolower))
my.corpus <- tm_map(my.corpus, removeWords, stopwords("en"))
my.corpus <- tm_map(my.corpus, removePunctuation)
my.corpus <- tm_map(my.corpus, stripWhitespace)
my.corpus <- tm_map(my.corpus, removeNumbers)
my.corpus <- tm_map(my.corpus, removeWords, c("status","please","need","mail",
                                    "email","unable","re","fw","st","th","sep","nov","thank","kmmvlkm","prb"))
my.corpus <- tm_map(my.corpus, stemDocument)


## Create Term Docuemnt Matrix
dataframe_DF<-data.frame(text=unlist(sapply(my.corpus, `[`, "content")), stringsAsFactors=F)
term.doc.matrix.desc <- TermDocumentMatrix(my.corpus)
term.doc.matrix <- as.matrix(term.doc.matrix.desc)


#--------------------------------# Feature Engineering Ends#-----------------------------------------------------


#--------------------------------# Implement TF-IDF Weighting Starts#-----------------------------------------------------
get.tf.idf.weights <- function(tf.vec, df) {
  # Computes tfidf weights from a term frequency vector and a document
  # frequency scalar
  weight = rep(0, length(tf.vec))
  weight[tf.vec > 0] = (1 + log2(tf.vec[tf.vec > 0])) * log2(N.docs/df)
  weight
}

get.weights.per.term.vec <- function(tfidf.row) {
  term.df <- sum(tfidf.row[1:N.docs] > 0)
  tf.idf.vec <- get.tf.idf.weights(tfidf.row, term.df)
  return(tf.idf.vec)
}


tfidf.matrix <- t(apply(term.doc.matrix.desc, c(1), FUN = get.weights.per.term.vec))
colnames(tfidf.matrix) <- colnames(term.doc.matrix.desc)

tfidf.matrix <- scale(tfidf.matrix, center = FALSE, scale = sqrt(colSums(tfidf.matrix^2)))

query.vector <- tfidf.matrix[, (N.docs + 1)]
tfidf.matrix <- tfidf.matrix[, 1:N.docs]

doc.scores <- t(query.vector) %*% tfidf.matrix
```

I am searching statement "Healthy cat food abcdefxyz", when I search "Healthy cat food" doc.scores provides correct information and throws results and provide scores for each document, but when i add some word which were not present in the document for example : "abcdefxyz" it is not providing results and give NaN for each document.

Can anyone help me and let me know why this is not giving results when I add extra word in text which needs to search in available list of documents.

Comment: I guess it's because `N.docs/df` yields a division by zero for terms that are only present in the query (`sum(tfidf.row[1:N.docs] > 0)` is `0`), thus the result gets `Inf`, and thus your `doc.scores` also "breaks" after matrix multiplication.

Comment: Be careful of which "search engine" you intend to use. Most folks don't seem to care at all about site terms of service (they would be data thieves) but if you pass these to google and scrape the results you're violating their terms of service. LinkedIn just slapped a huge fine on folks this year for terms of service violation, so it's not just a pedantic warning, either.

Comment: @hrbmstr I am just trying to replicate word search engine shared in blog https://www.r-bloggers.com/build-a-search-engine-in-20-minutes-or-less/ . This is just basic text mining,

Comment: @lukeA Thanks for your help think if I replace syntax weight[tf.vec > 0] = (1 + log2(tf.vec[tf.vec > 0])) * log2(N.docs/df) with weight[tf.vec > 0] = (1 + log2(tf.vec[tf.vec > 0])), it will provide me required results. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: That would remove the document frequency weighting, wouldn't it? I'd do sth like `if (df==0) return(rep(0, length(tf.vec)))`

Comment: @lukeA thanks you very much for your help, I have added above code in function now getting correct frequency weighting .